# Problems with 2d arrays in CCC 2018 j4 problem

Tags: python, ccc

I'm working on an question that's part of the CCC(question: https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc18s2) I have my code, but it doesnt work all the time. When I input my code into the online grader (which can be found on the linked page) I only get 3/15 marks. All the inputs I put in myself seem to work out, but the grader seems to be different.

My code:

```
lowest_val = []
flower=[]

n = int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    flower.append(input().split(" "))

lowest_val.append(flower[0][0])
lowest_val.append(flower[0][n-1])
lowest_val.append(flower[n-1][0])
lowest_val.append(flower[n-1][n-1])

while True:
    if flower[0][0] == min(lowest_val):
        for row in flower:
            for i in row:
                print(i, end=" ")
            print()
        break
    flower = list(zip(*flower[::-1]))
```

To answer this question, I can simply check if the top left corner is the smallest corner, so `flower[0][0]` must be the smallest corner.

`min()` looks for the smallest number out of the 4 corner that I added to the list `lowest_val`.

I cant find a test where this fails, and that might be my biggest problem. On dmoj (the online grader) all it does is say I got part of the question wrong.

Comment: * What type is `flower[0][0]`?
* What does `min()` return on a list of this type?
* Can you construct a test case where this fails, or should we provide one?

Comment: To answer this question, I can simply check if the top left corner is the smallest corner(flower[0][0] must be the smallest corner). min() looks for the smallest number out of the 4 corner that I added to the list lowest_val. I cant find a test where this fails, and that might be my biggest problem. On dmoj (the online grader) all it does is say I got part of the question wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test case that fails with your code:

```
2
10 4
3 2
```

Can you find out why it fails?

Comment: Ohh, I added the list corners into another list, but they were strings, not integers. It checked which one was lowest alphabetically. Just fixed it by converting them to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out why my code didn't work all the time:

When I added the list corners to `lowest_val` the elements were all strings, not integers.

Because of that, `min(lowest_val)` got me the lowest value, sorted alphabetically.

To solve it I simply made all the elements integers.